# Getting tables used inside User Defined Functions

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get all the tables and views used inside a user defined function? Is there any defined procedure to get that by passing the udf name?

```
create function sample_function
return table
as
return
   select *
   from table1 t1
   join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

I need to get `table1` and `table2` when i pass `sample_function` to any procedure.

Any Ideas would help.

Comment: Are you seeking a way to duplicate the SSMS *Show Dependencies* functionality from an actual SQL query? If not, please explain in more detail what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT DISTINCT referenced_entity_name FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.fn_sample','OBJECT')
```

EDIT:
Use the below query, to get only the referenced tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT referenced_entity_name 
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.fn_sample','OBJECT') ro
    INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON (ro.referenced_id = so.id)
WHERE so.xtype = 'U'
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and it is listing all the entities, is there a specific way to find tables alone ?

Comment: @SSS, Welcome! Updated the answer with the query to get only the tables